# Firebase Messaging in Xamarin v60.1142.0

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create a new app with FirebaseMessaging by using Xamarin.

I followed the instructions listed [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/data-and-cloud-services/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm/) step by step. I installed the NuGet, I got the google-service.json and I implemented my IID-, and Messaging Service. But when I try to send a notification via FirebaseConsole I just get nothing. I implemented a view to list all running processes, but my services are not among them.

I currently using Xamarin.Firebase.* and Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.* in v60.1142.0.

It's some kind of annoying as moved from AndroidStudio/Java to Xamarin/C# to implement ios later and it worked before in java.

I don't know, what I should provide, so the question is simple:

Is or was anyone facing the same problem like me?

And is there a way to fix that issue?

Is there something missing in the tutorial?

Should I use another NuGet version (32.* as in the tutorial)?

If need some code snippets, feel free to ask.

**Attachments**

```
abd logcat | grep -E "Firebase|incident"
```

[here](https://pastebin.com/wnw42JGG)

Adding Service and IntentFilter leads to the flowing Manifest entries:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="md5d8604714a1ecdc55ebbafaa700ab31f1.InstanceIDService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="md5d8604714a1ecdc55ebbafaa700ab31f1.MessagingService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Check the `logcat` output to see Firebase is not initializing.

Comment: There is another very comprehensive guide, which I found far better than the Xamarin one here: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter5/android/
That might help you track the issue down.

Comment: added logcat. As far as I can see, Firebase does not complain. But it looks like non of my services is running (even the NotFirebase services)

Comment: Have you add [[Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/)]?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried with and without [Service] and also added the flags I know from my java implementation like (Enabled = true, Exported=true). The services appear within the Manifest as expected (see Attachments)

Comment: Update: I started both services by using MainActivity.startService and now it works. But I guess that's not the way how it should be done.